# Есть ли ограничения на количество писем при отправке через SMTP (PHPmailer)?

Tags: php, smtp, email

PHP-скрипт отправляет письма через несколько сотен почтовых аккаунтов
через SMTP с помощью PHPmailer. Пару сотен писем отправляются, а затем
перестают доходить до адресата (не приходят на тестовые адреса). Ссылка,
используемая в письме, для каждой отправки генерируется новая, через
сервисы коротких ссылок. Темы и тексты рандомизируются.

Из-за чего может отрубаться отправка? Может ли быть такое, что
блокировка происходит из-за того, что слишком много писем с одного
домена (сервера)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ограничения есть как у хостеров, на котором ваш сайт, так и у почтовых сервисов типа яндекса, google, mail.ru и им подобных.

Чтобы правильно делать рассылку, необходимо:

- выделенный ip (как правило, для этого необходимо выделенный сервер - виртуальный или физический);
- настроить правильно почтовый сервер (включая SPF и DKIM);
- ознакомиться с рекомендациями по массовой рассылке у почтовых сервисов ([пример](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?hl=ru)) и донастроить свой почтовый сервер.

Как правило, мелкие сайты этим не заморачиваются (тут вопрос цены) и используют [сервисы почтовых рассылок](https://www.google.by/?q=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от настроек SMTP. Нормальные админы ставят ограничение на количество отправляемых писем за определенное время. Возможно у вас все письма отправляются с одним обратным адресом и система их отфильтровывает или еще по какому-нибудь признаку. Возможно на сервере, где заведены тестовые адреса, включается спам-фильтр и письма просто не принимаются. Для борьбы со спамом уже много чего придумали.